# AJAX Response Cannot Access Value Returned

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have generated an AJAX to help me with a create account and I have it returning the proper values, but now I cannot access these values. When the ajax returns and I `console.log(this.reponse)` this is what is outputted:

```
  {"errors":{"username":"Username is required.","email":"Email is required.","pass":"Password is 
  required.","con":"Confirmation Password is required."},"status":"error"}
```

When I try to do `this.response.errors`, I get an undefined message. I have also tried `this.response["errors"]` and I get the same thing. How do I get access to the values such as username, email, pass, and con. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is that a `reponse` or `response`?

Answer (score 0):

use `JSON.parse()` for json response to object

Try

```
var obj = JSON.parse(this.response)
console.log(obj.errors.username)
```